# Codeigniter get database value in controller

Tags: codeigniter, controller

This is my controller

```
  function index($id=NULL)
    {
         $this->load->model('article');

        $id= $this->uri->segment(3);
          $data = array('article' => $this->article->show_a_article($id),
            'sidebar' => $this->article->side_bar(9),
            'related'=>  $this->article->related_keyword($article_title),
        );
          echo $article->News_News_ID;

         $this->load->view('page/baiviet',$data);

    }
```

I want to get `article_title` value from table article and put it in `related_workword()` function.

Update model The show a article model is to get article detail. The second model is to get all article related to the chosen article.

```
 function show_a_article($id)
    {
        $query=  $this->db->get_where('news_news', array('News_News_ID'=>$id));
        return $query->row();
    }
    function related_keyword($rkey)
    {

        $sql="SELECT `News_News_ID`,`News_News_Headline`,`News_News_thumb1` FROM `news_news` WHERE `news_tags` like '%$rkey%' ORDER BY `News_News_ID` desc LIMIT 10";

        $query=  $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();


    }
```

Update: Igot it

```
echo $this->article->show_a_article($id)->News_News_Headline;
```

Comment: what is your model can you show your model

Comment: Kindly check the update

Comment: can please say what is your error

Comment: No error I don't know how to do.
'related'=>  $this->article->related_keyword($article_title),
 How to get article_title here I can get the id from url but after that How to get the title

Comment: if you want to check data is store into `related` than `print_r($data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call model method from controller

```
$article_title = $this->article->get_article_details($id)->article_title;
```

Add function in model to return data.

```
function get_article_details($id)
{
    $query = 'select article_title from table where col = '.$this->db->escape($id);
    return $this->db->query($query)->row();

}
```

Comment: Can u check again my question I just update my model. You answer is make sense but my model return array value. I want to get only one item.

Comment: Nam Hao :
1) if its returning array of values then you have to use index to read values from array.
2) if you want to return only only value then use row instead of result.